# issue Elfinder+CodeIgniter: I get {"error":["errUnknownCmd"]} when opening files

Tags: php, codeigniter, integration, elfinder

I've integrated Elfinder in a CodeIgniter 2 site, following [this](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-Codeigniter-2) instructions. In the view, I load Elfinder on a bootstrap modal.

Everything is working fine, except that when double-clicking on a file (Open) I get a new window with this error:

> {"error":["errUnknownCmd"]}

However, if I right-click->preview o right-click->download I can preview or download the file without problems.

After long search and test, I don't really understand why is this happening.

My controller:

```
<?php
class ex_cont extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        applogin_check();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->elfinder_init();
        return;
    }

    private function elfinder_init()
    {
      $this->load->helper('path');
      $opts = array(
        // 'debug' => true, 
        'roots' => array(
          array( 
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
            'path'          => '../../download-area',         
            'accessControl' => 'access',
            'defaults' => array('read' => true, 'write' => false)
          ) 
        )
      );
      $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/elfinder/css/elfinder.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/elfinder/css/theme.css">

<script src="/elfinder/js/elfinder.min.js"></script>
<script src="/elfinder/js/i18n/elfinder.ca.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            url : '/utilities/ex_cont'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
            , lang: 'ca'                    // language (OPTIONAL)
            , resizable: false
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="elfinder"></div>
```

Any suggestion about what else can I check? ...I start to be tempted to overwrite double-click handler. :P

I've tested it both in a Linux+apache and Windows+xampp environements. Same issue.

Comment: I suspect the problem might be related with a pretty complex routing scheme of my CI2 setup. :P

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: http://www.webolar.com/demo/elfinder.zip

and its training :
http://www.webolar.com/blog/blog/item/file-manager-codeigniter-elfinder

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Gio. Unfortunatelly is not really useful. Target web is written in arabic language  (?) and the automatic google translation is a little confusing. But there are several other similar examples around implementing what is described in the link I mentioned in the question [link](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-Codeigniter-2). But none of this help me to solve the 'errUnknownCmd' issue. I've a workaround working(overwriting js callback action), but is not a real solution.

Comment: That example worked well for me, try to check the demo.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's to late for you, but maybe useful for somebody else.

try add elfinder_init function on url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        url : '/utilities/ex_cont/elfinder_init'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        , lang: 'ca'                    // language (OPTIONAL)
        , resizable: false
    });
});
```